# SQL : Copying records within same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

SQL Server 2008 Table: table1

```
ID  DESC     TYP   SUBSET  VAL1   VAL2   VAL3   VAL4  PReview   Country

 1   DESC1    1      1      1.0    1.1   1.2    1.2    0         1
 2   DESC1    1      1      2.0    1.1   1.2    1.2    0         1
 3   DESC1    1      1      1.0    1.1   1.2    1.2    0         1 
 4   DESC2    2      1      3.0    2.1   1.7    1.8    0         1
 5   DESC2    2      1      4.0    3.1   1.7    1.9    0         1
 6   DESC2    2      1      5.0    6.1   1.5    1.6    0         1 
13   DESC1    1      1      1.0    1.1   1.2    1.2    1         1
14   DESC1    1      1      2.0    1.1   1.2    1.2    1         1
15   DESC1    1      1      1.0    1.1   1.2    1.2    1         1 

16   DESC2    2      1      1.0    6.1   1.7    1.2    1         1
17   DESC2    2      1      2.0    4.1   6.2    8.2    1         1
18   DESC2    2      1      1.0    8.1   7.2    1.9    1         1
```

I need to copy records which have preview = 1 into records which have preview 0. There is no way to uniquely define each record..just that they shoul dbe copied in an orderly manner. 
Record 13 should be copied to Record 1
Record 14 should be copied to Record 2
Record 15 should be copied to Record 3

Thanks.

Comment: "There is no way to uniquely define each record"... the `ID` column looks unique.  Is it not??

Comment: Will there be an identical number of rows with preview = 0 and preview  = 1?

Comment: -1 for a halfhearted question - nowhere near enough detail, very poor description of what you are trying to do and how your algorithm works. What does 'copy into' entail? How are you determining which record is 'copied into' which associated record? After you 'copy into', what happens to the original row / target row?

Comment: In addition to @Kirk's comment: What happens if there are more rows with `Preview=0` than with `Preview=1`? Or the other way?

Comment: @Shark:  Yeah ID col uniquely identifies the rows...my bad ...actually that col doesn't help me to copy the data from preview to non-preview rows ...the preview rows are deleted and recreated twice a day.. so while copying this col isn't of any use...

Comment: @ADam ..yeah there are identical number of rows for preview = 0 and preview = 1

Comment: With an identical number of rows, you can use something along the lines of what @BrankoDimitrijevic has proposed.

Comment: @Kirk  I am sorry if I wasn't clear about my problem.. but other people have given good suggestions even with the precise & ambiguous info i had provided.  Ok, i will try to explain the workflow. Data is exported from excel sheet into preview rows and is displayed to admin..if the admin finds everything ok with the data it is copied to non preview rows and displayed to the users. The first preview row should be copied to first non preview row within the same group.The no of rows in preview & non preview within a group are same.

Comment: @shazia What is the purpose of leaving original rows in the table after they have been "approved" by the administrator? After all, they are identical to the new copies (violating the DRY principle - Google it), except for the ID. Do you have something connected to this ID that you can't break away from? I suspect there are better ways of managing this whole situation by using a different data model...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is to "enumerate" (i.e. attach indexes to) both source and destination rows and then assign the source row with index 1 to the destination row with index 1, source row with index 2 to the destination row with index 2 etc:

```
UPDATE TABLE1
SET
    [DESC] = SOURCE.[DESC],
    TYP = SOURCE.TYP,
    SUBSET = SOURCE.SUBSET,
    VAL1 = SOURCE.VAL1,
    VAL2 = SOURCE.VAL2,
    VAL3 = SOURCE.VAL3,
    VAL4 = SOURCE.VAL4,
    PREVIEW = SOURCE.PREVIEW,
    COUNTRY = SOURCE.COUNTRY
FROM (
    SELECT DEST_ID, SRC.*
    FROM
        (SELECT ID DEST_ID, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ID) R FROM TABLE1 WHERE PREVIEW = 0) DEST
        JOIN (SELECT *, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ID) R FROM TABLE1 WHERE PREVIEW = 1) SRC
            ON SRC.R = DEST.R
) SOURCE
WHERE TABLE1.ID = SOURCE.DEST_ID
```

In plain English:

- Attach indexes to rows where PREVIEW = 0, in order of ID (`RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ID)`).
- Do the same where PREVIEW = 1.
- Match source to destination indexes (`JOIN ... ON SRC.R = DEST.R`).
- Update the table based on that matching.

---

Please be careful when number of destination rows is smaller than the number of source rows - the initial query execution will not update all the destination rows and the **second execution** may lead to the same source row being copied to a **different** destination row.

In effect, you'd be copying the same source row to multiple destination rows.

Comment: @Branko..thanks for the reply & suggestion. I will try it...however I have never used indexes before and am not sure what changes I need ot make to your solution to get going:

Comment: I have updated my sample data..can you have a look at it and see whether your solution will work with it..Meanwhile I will scratch my head to understand the indexes. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @shazia I don't see why my solution wouldn't work with new test data, if you take care of caveats I already described. Did you actually try it? Does it do what you want?

Comment: @shazia Just to make it clear, I used the word "index" in a sense it would be used in some procedural language (i.e. a number), **not** in the sense of the database index (i.e. `CREATE INDEX ...`). The `RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ID)` essentially means: mark the rows with 1, 2, 3... in order defined by ID. Try running the just the `(SELECT ... FROM TABLE1 WHERE PREVIEW = 0) DEST JOIN (SELECT ... FROM TABLE1 WHERE PREVIEW = 1) SRC ON SRC.R = DEST.R` portion of the query to see what you get as a result without actually updating the table - this might help you understand the basic idea better.

Comment: Thanks Branko ...your soultion worked like a charm...perfecto!!!. Sorry i was wrong about the index... here is a link which I found quite helpful in understanding the Rank functionality http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1944/sql-server-2005-and-2008-ranking-functions-rownumber-and-rank/.Once again Branko thanks for your help.

Comment: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1944/sql-server-2005-and-2008-ranking-functions-rownumber-and-rank/

Answer (score 1):

If you need the records to "copy over" the preview = 0 records, couldn't you just:

- Delete the `preview = 0` records
- Replicate each `preview = 1` record so you have two copies of each.

This sounds like what you're asking for.

Comment: Thanks Adam for the suggestion..however I can't delete the preview = 0 records as these are linked to other tables.It would have worked if I didn't need the identity column